# display all avarage rating review

Tags: magento-1.9, review, ratings

I need to display the average of all the product reviews in magento.

I need if you can view it in this way
[image: decimal avarage]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code might help you:

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)->setDateOrder()->addRateVotes();

$avg = 0;
$totalrv = 0;
$totalrvper =0;
$ratings = array();

if (count($reviews) > 0) {
    foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
    foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {

        $totalrv = $totalrv+$vote->getValue();
        $totalrvper = $totalrvper + $vote->getPercent();

    }
}

$totalrv= ($totalrv/3)/4;
$totalrvper = ($totalrvper/3)/4;

$avgrate = round($totalrv, 1);
}
```

Comment: @yavonz15 if you want to improve Hitesh's answer, then please add an answer yourself